# How to require from the user entering a second input to a Discord Bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I’m trying to write a command that requires the user to enter another input after the initial entry. I’ve tried to create a client connection inside the file that contains the command module.

However, I’ve tried and researched with no results, when I enter the second input the bot doesn’t respond.

I’ve tried to pass the main argument into the command to see if the bot can receive another input but ended with evaluating the first one.

Here’s a sample of my first attempt of creating the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

ule.exports = {
 name: 'command',
 description: 'A test command',
 execute(message, args){
     if(args == '1'){
         message.channel.send('Enter another input');
         client.on('message', message =>{
             if(!message.content.length || message.author.bot) return;
             const args = message.content.slice().split();
             if(args == '2'){
                 message.channel.send('Done!');
             }
         });
     }
 }
}
```

I've thought of changing the name of the 'message' argument inside the 'client.on' function but I got the same results, I'm not sure if its scope is only inside the function and not just a passed argument from the 'execute' function

Comment: I was looking at documentation, have you tried doing it this way? https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/master/code-samples/creating-your-bot/adding-more-commands/index.js

Comment: No actually, I use a module for every single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either make an [awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

```js
     if(!args[0]) return
     if(!args[1])
     {
        message.channel.send('Enter another input').then(m => {
            const m = await msg.channel.awaitMessages((mes) => mes.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 50000, errors: ['time'] }).catch(err => console.log(err))
            args[1] = m.first();
        })  
     }
```

Either if there is not second argument you just don't run the command

```js
     if(!args[0]) return
     if(!args[1]) return message.reply("You need to insert the second argument")
```